# Unable to insert multiple rows containing huge Twitter Response strings in MySQL DB?

Tags: php, mysql, twitter, mysqli, twitter-streaming-api

The following is the code that adds 200 recent tweets (JSON provided by Twitter API) into the DB for a Twitter-User. Here the  `$users` array just holds one user (eg: @katyperry) but eventually it would hold more. For each of the users in the array 200 tweets are being brought in through the Twitter API. All this data collection works fine.

**Here is the problem now**: For each user I am inserting 200 tweets in the MySQL DB (I have to use MySQL only, no other choice) table. Now I understand that each `TwitterResp` JSON stringified is huge (maybe that is the issue).

Example of TwitterResp:

```
{"created_at":"Thu Jul 23 18:25:30 +0000 2015","id":624284214704390145,"id_str":"624284214704390145","text":"when your fragrance is ud83dudd25#madpotion https://t.co/UfyPQIwIj4","source":"<a href="http://instagram.com" rel="nofollow">Instagram</a>","truncated":false,"in_reply_to_status_id":null,"in_reply_to_status_id_str":null,"in_reply_to_user_id":null,"in_reply_to_user_id_str":null,"in_reply_to_screen_name":null,"user":{"id":21447363,"id_str":"21447363","name":"KATY PERRY","screen_name":"katyperry","location":"","description":"CURRENTLYu2728BEAMINGu2728ON THE PRISMATIC WORLD TOUR 2014/2015!","url":"http://t.co/fxFJjKX30d","entities":{"url":{"urls":[{"url":"http://t.co/fxFJjKX30d","expanded_url":"http://www.katyperry.com","display_url":"katyperry.com","indices":[0,22]}]},"description":{"urls":[]}},"protected":false,"followers_count":73404466,"friends_count":157,"listed_count":143175,"created_at":"Fri Feb 20 23:45:56 +0000 2009","favourites_count":1663,"utc_offset":-28800,"time_zone":"Alaska","geo_enabled":false,"verified":true,"statuses_count":6566,"lang":"en","contributors_enabled":false,"is_translator":false,"is_translation_enabled":true,"profile_background_color":"CECFBC","profile_background_image_url":"http://pbs.twimg.com/profile_background_images/378800000168797027/kSZ-ewZo.jpeg","profile_background_image_url_https":"https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_background_images/378800000168797027/kSZ-ewZo.jpeg","profile_background_tile":false,"profile_image_url":"http://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/609748341119844352/7dUd606e_normal.png","profile_image_url_https":"https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/609748341119844352/7dUd606e_normal.png","profile_banner_url":"https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_banners/21447363/1428015534","profile_link_color":"D55732","profile_sidebar_border_color":"FFFFFF","profile_sidebar_fill_color":"78C0A8","profile_text_color":"5E412F","profile_use_background_image":true,"has_extended_profile":false,"default_profile":false,"default_profile_image":false,"following":true,"follow_request_sent":false,"notifications":false},"geo":null,"coordinates":null,"place":null,"contributors":null,"is_quote_status":false,"retweet_count":5366,"favorite_count":10510,"entities":{"hashtags":[{"text":"madpotion","indices":[24,34]}],"symbols":[],"user_mentions":[],"urls":[{"url":"https://t.co/UfyPQIwIj4","expanded_url":"https://instagram.com/p/5fRc5mP-YB/","display_url":"instagram.com/p/5fRc5mP-YB/","indices":[35,58]}]},"favorited":false,"retweeted":false,"possibly_sensitive":false,"lang":"en"}
```

So when I am inserting in a loop as shown in the code for `TwitterResp` being a huge string, in the end I see something like 154 rows in the table **not 200**. For some other user I see 186 **not 200** and so on. Now matter how many times I run the code for katy perry I get 154 only and similar for other users. I was wondering why may this be? Is the insertion process slow for this loop with huge string insertions that it is skipping some rows?

```
$users = array("result" => ["@katyperry"]);

    foreach ($users['result'] as $user) {

        // strip the initial character '@' and get 200 Twitter Responses for that screen-name.
        $twitterResp = getTweet(substr($user, 1), 200);

        $count = 1;

        mysqli_query(getConnection(), "START TRANSACTION;");

        foreach($twitterResp as $response){

            $object = $response;

            $query = "INSERT INTO Tweets(Number, TwitterHandle, TwitterResp) VALUES('".(string)$count."', '".$user."', '".json_encode($object)."');";

            $count += 1;

            $res = mysqli_query(getConnection(),$query);

        }
        mysqli_query(getConnection(), "COMMIT;");
    }
```

PS: I also tried adding the tweets in one query by basically Adding a lot of VALUES(), VALUES(), .....
That also didn't work.

How can I fix this? Any Suggestions?

Comment: What is the type of TwitterResp column?

Comment: The type of TwitterResp is TEXT. I should probably change it to MEDIUMTEXT.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At first, modify your code to handle MySQL errors. This will definitely give you a hint what's going wrong.

```
$res = mysqli_query(getConnection(),$query);
if(false === $res) {
   echo "Insertion error: " . mysqli_error();
}
```

My guess is that you're exceeding max length for `TEXT` or `BLOB` type, whatever you've used for TwitterResp column.

It may seem that data length for `TEXT` or `BLOB` type is unlimited, but it's not. `TEXT` / `BLOB` may handle up to 65536 bytes (~64KB), while `MEDIUMTEXT` / `MEDIUMBLOB` have capacity of ~16MB and `LONGTEXT` / `LONGBLOB` up to ~4GB.

Note that these are only type limits, you also have to consider size of connection buffer, number of available memory, etc, which may also cause data truncation. See [MySQL documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/blob.html) for more info.

In conclusion, you may try to change column type to `MEDIUMTEXT` or `MEDIUMBLOB` which have higher capacity. Yet if it is not enough I'd suggest to store data in file instead and save file path into database.

Comment: I tried MEDIUMTEXT and LONGTEXT. Both didn't work. That was very weird but checking the mysqli error was very helpful. Through that I got to know the issue was that for some TwitterResp the INSERTION syntax was getting disrupted as the TwitterResp had a character ' in it. Maybe in like a tweet 
eg:
"My car's window is broken"

So I string replaced ' and escaped it all (\'). That worked and now I see 200 Tweets.

Comment: You may be interested in this question also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php